# Why Are Columns Used for a Single Category of Data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Background**

I work on a manufacturing site. As part of my daily routine, I walk through the site and collect (write with pen and paper) data from all the analog gauges our system isn't able to log. The rounds sheet I use generally looks like this:

```
╔══════════════════════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ Date                 ║ M     ║ T     ║ W     ║ Th    ║ F     ║
╠══════════════════════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║                      ║ 10/14 ║ 10/15 ║ 10/16 ║ 10/17 ║ 10/18 ║
║ Pump Inlet Pressure  ║   60  ║   60  ║   60  ║   55  ║   60  ║
║                      ║       ║       ║       ║       ║       ║
║ Pump Outlet Pressure ║ 100   ║  100  ║  110  ║  105  ║  110  ║
║                      ║       ║       ║       ║       ║       ║
╚══════════════════════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

An actual rounds sheet is 3 pages long with almost one hundred different points I collect data from. I have been tasked with entering 100s of these handwritten rounds sheets into Excel.

When I started entering the rounds in, the first thing I did was make the date a single column and each data point I collect from its own column. The Excel sheet I made looks like:

```
╔═══════╦═════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ Date  ║ Pump Inlet Pressure ║ Pump Outlet Pressure ║
╠═══════╬═════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 10/14 ║                  60 ║                  100 ║
║ 10/15 ║                  60 ║                  100 ║
║ 10/16 ║                  60 ║                  110 ║
║ 10/17 ║                  55 ║                  105 ║
║ 10/18 ║                  60 ║                  110 ║
╚═══════╩═════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

For me, this seems like the correct way to design the table in Excel. In my mind, it will make creating charts, looking at trends, etc. easier. But my boss has always formatted tables like the top table.

**Questions**

Which one of these design tables will be the easiest to work with? Why do we typically have a single column represent one category of data? Is there some underlying mathematical convention? Or is there a low-level computer science reason, e.g., allocating memory spaces is easier when vertically oriented? Is this some basic 5th-grade level math that I've completely forgotten?

From a practical perspective, the top table prints onto paper much better and it can be easier to see a single week's worth of data on a computer screen. But most of the Excel tools I use seem to default to working with vertical data, like in the bottom table.

Comment: This question is too subjective for this site. You've already listed arguments for both options. It's really up to just you and your boss to agree which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top table is *presentation* the bottom table is *data*.

The convention for uniform columns is to ensure data is not polluted by commentary or irrelevant information and/or white space that will need to be parsed. Unfortunately, excel is a poor choice if you want to enforce data integrity.

While Excel (and similar) can be used for data as in your second table, it is not very good as an actual store for data: a proper database is a better option since that type of software is built for: segmentation, complex cross-referencing, data validation, error-checking and file consistency, retrieval performance across arbitrary volumes of data etc. etc.

There are many arguments against using a spreadsheet as a database--too many to iterate here, but for further reading try: "stop using excel as a database" and "database vs spreadsheet".

Note that database data is often *presented visually* nearly identically to a spreadsheet as in your second example. This is also just a convention: in reality the data presented may be joined database tables and sub-queries pulled from other sources. Database software is a very powerful tool for working with well-structured data.

Comment: You may also want to look at data base normalization, also. If a Windows user Microsoft Access is a start on database use.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I looked up those readings and it has given me some things to think about. I'm going to look into whether or not a database would be appropriate for this situation.

Comment: One of the problems many people have is that their office culture/training/software availability *forces* excel use on them